# The provided role does not have sufficient permissions. (Service: AmazonAppConfig)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-app-config

I created the following:

- AppConfig, which have configurationProfile (the source is CodePipeline)
- CodeCommit
- CodeBuild
- Code pipeline.

I configured code pipeline to deploy into AppConfig when a change happen to test.json file that exist in CodeCommit.

However, each deployment attmpt fail with the following error:

> BadRequestException caught while trying to start deployment for
> application j3wn7j2, environment 2df8rwe, configuration profile
> abcata7, with version ee00d908-0235-4a7a-aba1-70cd2e0fda90. Message:
> Unable to access the artifact with Amazon S3 object key
> 'qwrqwrqwr/BuildArtif/TVsQbS0' located in the Amazon S3 artifact
> bucket 'codepipeline-eu-west-1-634809616452'. **The provided role does
> not have sufficient permissions. (Service: AmazonAppConfig**; Status
> Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID:
> 18947231-10d8-4914-93d3-badcf442aca8; Proxy: null)

What I tried to do:

- Checked the IAM role for CodePipeline and for sure it had S3 permissions
- Tried to give AppConfig permission to read from an S3 bucket but **couldn't find anywhere to attach an Iam role to an AmazonAppConfig resource.**
- added the following policy to the S3 (codepipeline-eu-west-1-634809616452):

> {
> "Version": "2012-10-17",
> "Id": "SSEAndSSLPolicy",
> "Statement": [
> {
> "Sid": "admin",
> "Effect": "Allow",
> "Principal": {
> "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::044559349107:root"
> },
> "Action": "s3:GetObject",
> "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-eu-west-1-634809616452/*"
> }
> ] }

Am I missing something???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, which has nothing to do with permissions!
I just added artifacts step in CodeBuild:

```
version: 0.2
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

And it's fixed.